# How to have every instance of character typed in bold in filter as you type list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As an example, if I have 'vegetables' in my list and I type a letter 'e', all three letter 'e's in 'vegetables' should become bold. I have played around with the code at the fiddles I found on the web below, but with them, I can only get the beginning of the words bold or the middle of words.

https://jsfiddle.net/ku5zv3dz/

```
      var inputId   = 'mytextbox';
var itemsData   = 'value';
var displaySet = false;
var displayArr = [];

function getDisplayType(element) {
    var elementStyle = element.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(element, "");
    return elementStyle.display;
}

document.getElementById(inputId).onkeyup = function() {
  var currval = this.value;
    var searchVal = this.value.toLowerCase();
    var filterItems = document.querySelectorAll('[' + itemsData + ']');
    for(var i = 0; i < filterItems.length; i++) {
        if (!displaySet) {
            displayArr.push(getDisplayType(filterItems[i]));
        }
    var textcontent = filterItems[i].textContent;
    var replacedval = "<strong>"+currval+"</strong>"
    var finalval = textcontent.replace(currval, replacedval);
   filterItems[i].innerHTML = finalval;
        filterItems[i].style.display = 'none';
        if(filterItems[i].getAttribute('value').toUpperCase().indexOf(searchVal.toUpperCase()) >= 0) {
            filterItems[i].style.display = displayArr[i];       
        }
    }
    displaySet = true;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/noth1ng/ytYQd/

```
      $('#mytextbox').keyup(function () {
    var valThis = this.value.toLowerCase(),
        length  = this.value.length;

    $('#mydropdown>option').each(function () {
        var text  = $(this).text(),
            textL = text.toLowerCase(),
            htmlR = '<b>' + text.substr(0, length) + '</b>' + text.substr(length);
        (textL.indexOf(valThis) == 0) ? $(this).html(htmlR).show() : $(this).hide();
    });

});
```

This is the original code before trying to add the feature for bold:

```
jQuery.fn.filterByText = function(mytextbox) {
  return this.each(function() {
    var select = this;
    var options = [];
    $(mydropdown).find('option').each(function() {
      options.push({
        value: $(this).val(),
        text: $(this).text()
      });
    });
    $(mydropdown).data('options', options);
    $(mytextbox).bind('change keyup', function() {
      var options = $(mydropdown).empty().data('options');
      var search = $.trim($(this).val().replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&"));
      var regex = new RegExp(search, "gi");

      $.each(options, function(i) {
        var option = options[i];
        if (option.text.match(regex) !== null) {
          $(mydropdown).append(
            $('<option>').text(option.text).val(option.value)
          );
        }
      });

    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Use `var finalval = textcontent.replace(new RegExp(currval, 'g'), replacedval);`

Comment: Sorry 4castle, didn't see your reply till now. Is that line all that needs to be added to the original code? I am not sure where it needs to be placed within the original code. Thanks.

Comment: The line I gave should replace the line that currently assigns to `finalval`.

Comment: Thanks 4castle. Sorry for the confusion; the code you have kindly provided does work perfectly in the first code in my post, however, when I stated 'original code', I meant the code that I started with (the last one in my post), not the ones with links to fiddles. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used the valThis to create the RegExp and use the replace method to replace all occurrences with the bold value.

```
$('#box').keyup(function () {
var valThis = this.value.toLowerCase(),
    lenght  = this.value.length;

    $('.navList>li').each(function () {
        var text  = $(this).text(),
            textL = text.toLowerCase();

        var replace = "(" + valThis + ")";
        var re = new RegExp(replace,"g");

        textL = textL.replace(re,"<b>" + valThis + "</b>");

        $(this).html(textL);
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/54rya8p4/

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. At my end, only the beginning of the words are appearing in bold. In the following fiddle, if I type a letter 'e', all three letter 'e's in 'Vege tables' should become bold and the 'e' in 'Meats' also. https://jsfiddle.net/djj2c84t/6/